# Python print 2D list

Tags: python, list

I want sepreate my 2 dimensional list but dont know how.
How can I seperate them ?

Print data gives me this output:

```
print data
```

`[(array([ 1.]), 0.0), (array([ 0.]), 0.0), (array([ 0.]), 0.0),......`.

I want the output like:

```
print data1[0]
```

> 1. , 0. , 0. , ...

```
print data2[1]
```

> 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 , ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `for` loop:

```
for arr in data:
    print(arr)
```

However, the contents of `data` appear to be tuples `(single-element-array, float)`, which seems a bit strange.

Comment: How can I collect them in a list ?

Comment: Collect what in a list? Where are you getting `data` from?